# How to get all the names of photos only which are saved in documents folder of iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, nsfilemanager

i want to get all the photos names saved in my documents folder .as it contains some resources other than images,i need to select the images itelf from the documents folder and populate the names of images in an array.

Comment: Good luck on that. Unless you don't specify which language do you intend to use, nobody can help you.

Comment: i have tagged it iphone ...which means objective c and iphone

Comment: are the images guaranteed to having the correct file extensions? are those extensions limited to a fixed number of image types?

Comment: @JamesWebster yes i am saving them all in .png format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDir error:nil];
NSArray *onlyPics = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"]];
```