# How to load PDFs from Documents Directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I can load list of pdf files(all pdf files) from Resources folder, using this code.

```
 NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

But I couldn't find a method to load list of pdf files from Documents Directory. The following line of code can **only load one** pdf at a time.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
NSURL *urlPdf = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: file];
```

How could I load **all pdf files from Documents Directory**

Can you please give me a code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue using this line of code :)

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *pdfs = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with [NSFileManager's contentsOfDirectoryAtPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and filter the result by hand for pdf files.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865544/how-to-get-all-the-names-of-photos-only-which-are-saved-in-documents-folder-of-i) maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *filesAtPath = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:error];

for (NSString *path in filesAtPath) 
{
    if ([path rangeOfString:@".pdf"].length > 0)
    {
        //Do whatever you want with the pdf file
    }
}
```

I hope it helps, cheers